# Servo keeps rotating

Tags: arduino-uno, c++, servo, potentiometer

I use a 360° servo with a program I made on an Arduino Uno.

The program was meant to control two separate servos with two potentiometers on a breadboard.

When I used 180° and 90° servos, it worked fine, but when the 180° servo was swapped with a 360° servo, it kept spinning and spinning non-stop.

Could it be the knock-off board (not Arduino brand) I'm using?

```cpp
Servo serX;    // create servo object to control a servo for x axis
Servo serY;    // create servo y axis

int pot1 = 0;  // potentiometer pin number on board
int pot2 = 1;  // potentiometer number 2
int val;       // variable to read the value from the analog pin
int val2;      // read value from other analog pin

void setup() {
  serX.attach(9);  // attaches the servo on pin 9 to the servo object
  serY.attach(10); // attach servo to number 10 pin
}

void loop() {
  val = analogRead(pot1);           // reads the value of the potentiometer
  val = map(val, 0, 1023, 0, 180);  // scale it to use it with the servo
  serX.write(val);                  // sets the servo position
  
  val2 = analogRead(pot2);          // reads the value of the potentiometer
  val2 = map(val2, 0, 1023, 0, 90); // scale it to use it with the servo
  serY.write(val2);                 // sets the servo position
  
  delay(15);                        // waits for the servo to get there
}
```

Comment: Is this a "continuous rotation" servo? If so then the "angle" defines the speed and direction of rotation, with 90° normally being "stop".

Answer (score 3):

The "360°" you refer to is probably a [continuous-rotation servo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Servo_(radio_control)#Continuous-rotation_servos).

These servos behave more like motors than like the normal RC servos; the signal you send such a servo will determine its *speed* and *direction*, **not** its position, and a pulse width of 1.5 ms (the "90° setting") will make it stop.

There's an [article on the Adafruit site](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-motor-selection-guide/continuous-rotation-servos) where you can read more about this.